# What do you mean by "coordinate transformation of differential operators" , after all?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let $\varphi (u,v,w)$ be a **orthogonal coordinate transformation** from the $u,v,w$ coordinate system to the $x,y,$z coordinate system.
Let $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)$ be a vector field defined in $x,y,z$ space, and $f(x,y,z)$ be a scalar field defined in $x,y,z$ space.
Let $\xi$ be a differential operator acting on a function or vector field defined in x,y,z space.
(i.e, The $\xi$  is a differential operator that can act on $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)$ or $f$ above)

### My question.

> Am I right if I understand that a coordinate transformation by $\varphi$ of a differential operator $\xi$ is to find $\xi '$ such that;
>
> 1. $\xi'$ is a differential operator acting on a function or vector field defined in $u,v,w$ space.
> 2. $\xi'$ satisfies
>    $\xi\left[f\right]\left(\varphi\left(u,v,w\right)\right)=\left(\xi^\prime\left[\varphi^{*}f\right]\right)\left(u,v,w\right)
>    $  (for scalar field $f(x,y,z)$)
>    $\xi\left[\mathbf{F}\right]\left(\varphi\left(u,v,w\right)\right)=\left(\xi^\prime\left[\varphi^{*}\mathbf{F}\right]\right)\left(u,v,w\right)
>    $  (for vector field $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)$)
>    Here,
>
> - $\varphi^{*}f := f\circ \varphi$,
> - $\varphi^{*}\mathbf{F}= F_u \mathbf{t}_u + F_v \mathbf{t}_v + F_w \mathbf{t}_w$ ,
>   $\mathbf{t}_u(u,v,w):= \frac{1}{h_u(u,v,w)}\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial u}(u,v,w) 
>    ,\cdots ,$
>   $h_u(u,v,w):=\left\|\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial u}(u,v,w)\right\| , \cdots ,$
>   $ F_u(u,v,w):= <\mathbf{F}\circ\varphi (u,v,w)|\mathbf{t}_u(u,v,w)> ,\cdots ,$

Where

- $< | >$ represents inner product ,
- $\left\| \right\|$ represents norm ,
- $\xi\left[f\right]\left(\varphi\left(u,v,w\right)\right)$
  is the value of  at $\varphi\left(u,v,w\right)$ of
  $\xi\left[f\right]$,  $\xi\left[f\right]$ is what $\xi$ acts on $f$. (The same manner for vector fields.)
- $\cdots$